# Laravel get linked models through many-to-many relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have several classes with relations as follows:

```
class ProductModel extends Model
{
    function values()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\ParameterValue', 'model_values', 'model_id', 'value_id');
    }
}

class ParameterValue extends Model
{
    function parameter()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Parameter');
    }
}

class Parameter extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    function values()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ParameterValue');
    }
}
```

What i want to achieve, is to get all the `Parameter` entities from the `ProductModel` class via `ParameterValue` entity. Is there any way to achieve this without looping through all the values and grouping them by `parameter_id`? I want to achieve something like this:

```
class ProductModel extends Model
{
    function values()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\ParameterValue', 'model_values', 'model_id', 'value_id'); 
    }

    function parameters()
    {
         /** A list of App\Models\Parameter entities that corresponds to the model via values */         
         return ???;
    }
}
```

P. S. I'm sorry, made a mistake, `ParameterValue` `belongsTo` `Parameter`, not `hasOne`.

Comment: Something like this? :https://github.com/cruddy/playground/blob/master/app/ParameterValue.php

Comment: Updated a question for better understanding of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

> From the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#has-many-through)
>
> The "has many through" relation provides a convenient short-cut for accessing >distant relations via an intermediate relation.

```
class ProductModel extends Model
{
    function parameters()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Parameter', 'App\Models\ParameterValue');
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work this way, this is something like `belongsToManyThrough` but there is no such method in Laravel.

Comment: You need one more method in the ParameterValue model, cause it belongs to many ParameterModel.